# Use apache mod rewrite with php variable inside page

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mod-rewrite

I am displaying a record from a database by passing a GET parameter into a url: http://example.com/record?id=2

The record has a field named "title" that I would like to use to rewrite the url to display like this:
http://example.com/record/title

Example: http://example.com/record/This-is-the-Record-Title

Inside the page I have a variable $title that pulls the "title" value from the record. How can I use the $title variable to rewrite the variable like shown in the example above?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is two-fold:

1. Set up mod_rewrite to split the request into variables (use search for `mod_rewrite` topics), and
2. Create reverse routing which takes `This-is-the-Record-Title` and translates it into number 2

Hope that takes you where you are trying to go.

Answer (score 0):

Since the information about the title is not available to mod_rewrite, you will better set a redirect from PHP. Like:

```
/*** find out record title here ***/
$_SESSION['id'] = $_REQUEST['id'];
header('HTTP/1.1 302 Found');
header('Location: http://example.com/record/'.$record_title);
```

The id can be stored in a session variable, so you do not have to reverse-retrieve it. Still better would be to use a verified value, such as the id returned from the database row, because this is not prone to any modifications from user side. However, if users access the record via the "pretty link", you will have to lookup the record from the title.

For mod_rewrite, you should setup an internal rewrite, so the record title and not the actual script will be displayed to the users:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    "^/record/(.*)$"  "/records.php?title=$1" [PT]
```